# How to send FormData in MERN Stack project with TS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mern, tsx

I'm trying to send FormData to my backend but when I console.log the req.body it's empty object and I don't know why.

Here is my frontend request:

```
const createProduct = (e: any) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const data = new FormData()

        data.append("name", name)
        data.append("description", description)
        data.append("price", price)
        for (const colorAndImage of colorsAndImages) {
            data.append('images', colorAndImage.images[0]);
            data.append('colors', colorAndImage.colors);
        }
        data.append("type", type)

        fetch('http://localhost:4000/products/create', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: data
        })
```

Here is how the image file looks like in the console:

```
File {name: 'iphone_13_pro_max_gold_pdp_image_position-1a__wwen_5.jpg', lastModified: 1642862621798, lastModifiedDate: Sat Jan 22 2022 16:43:41 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: '', size: 22194, …}
```

Here is what I'm sending in the request in Network tab:

```
name: sdf
description: sdf
price: 234
images: (binary)
colors: red
type: sdf
```

Here is the controller in backend side:

```
productController.post('/create', async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    console.log(req)
    try {
        const data = req.body;
        let product = await create(data)
        res.status(201).json(product)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        //res.status(500).json({error: error})
    }
})
```

And what I see when I try to console.log the request:

```
{
  name: undefined,
  description: undefined,
  price: undefined,
  colors: undefined,
  images: undefined,
  type: undefined,
  likes: undefined
}
Error: Product validation failed: name: Path `name` is required., description: Path `description` is required., price: Path `price` is required., type: Path `type` is required.
```

My express config:

```
const corsConfig: cors.CorsOptions = {
    credentials: true,
    origin: ['http://localhost:3000', 'http://localhost:2000']
}

export default function (app: Application) {
    app.use(cors(corsConfig))
    
    app.use(cookieParser());

    app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    app.use(express.json())

    app.use(auth())
}
```

Comment: do you use bodyparser in backend?

Comment: actually no, u can check my updated question

Comment: I saw your comment on the @shivam answer, you need to use mutler in the case you want to upload images.

Comment: I know, but isn't that enough for now? First I want to see that the data is sending correct but... it's not

Comment: And even I don't send image as file, the other data is not sending

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why are you using FormData in sending raw data from frontend to backend.

FormData is generally used when you have to send (upload) files. For simple data you can just send JSON object.

Express by default can't parse `multipart/form-data`, you will have to install a middleware like [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) in order to get the data or you can update your data structure in frontend.

```
let dataToSend = {
  name: name,
  description: description,
  price: price

 // Rest of the properties
}
```

Comment: I'm sending images as files

Comment: Well It would have been a good idea to mention it in the question you asked ;) , but if you are sending images. You will have to plug in `multer` middleware.

Comment: I know but isn't that enough (without multer) to see the sended data ? Only to see that it's sending correct

Comment: And even I don't send image as file, the other data is not sending

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer, Express by default can't parse the `form-data` natively, so as per my understanding you will keep receiving `undefined` if you don't plug in the parser. I mean you are using JSON parser  `app.use(express.json())` in order to handle JSON data ;) because express can't parse JSON out of the box.

Comment: even if you don't send images, rest of the data is still in form of `form-data` and express can't parse it

Comment: Ohhhhhh I see, thank you so much, I didn't even notice. I thought that I need it only when I want to save it in the DB